# Remove elements from in memory element in js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a java script file that is used in several places. It has this code:

```
var newDiv = lastDiv.cloneNode(true);
```

lastDiv has some `<input>` elements that I do not want to clone. I've created these input elements with the attribute `<input copy="dont">` so that I could remove them out using the following code:

```
newDiv.select("input[copy=dont]").remove()
```

The prototype.js `select()` finds these elements. But `remove()` does not work, newDiv still has the input elements that I wanted filtered. Prototype documentation states that it will remove from the document, but newDiv is not in the document, it is only in memory.

**This is solved now**: `select()` was returning an array. If only prototype would have returned a meaningful error message. It was returning the list of matching elements. Thanks for your answers guys. Will use valid HTML5. This works now

```
newDiv.select("input[copy=dont]")[0].remove()
```

Comment: If you use the data attributes for HTML5 then your HTML will be valid. `copy` is not a standard HTML attribute. I'd would use `data-clonable="false"`.

Comment: @adeneo: Give it a rest.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Did you see the error in your console?

Comment: @adeneo - you should use c# :)

Comment: I don't use `prototypejs`, but here: `newDiv.select("input[copy=dont]").invoke("remove");`. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr4g4/). This invokes the method provided by the string on the items in the collection returned from `.select()`.

Comment: *"If only prototype would have returned a meaningful error message."* How can prototypejs give any error message? The only one you'll get will be that `.remove()` is not a function, which should be plenty.

Comment: And don't post your answer in your question. Post an actual answer if you wish, though that isn't going to be the way to do it if there are potentially several (or no) elements returned.

Comment: Well when it was returning the list of matching elements, I was under the impression that its almost working.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's just a type in your selector , try this:

```
newDiv.select("input[copy='dont']").remove()
```

also , just s suggestion , use the attribute `data-copy` instead of `copy` ex.

```
<input data-copy="dont" type="text" />
```

this will keep your elements valid HTML5

Comment: @cookiemonster - my first thought was invalid HTML was messing OP up in some browsers , then I thought why not try the quote thing , necessary in jQuery

Comment: @ScottSelby: The quotes aren't actually necessary in jQuery. That's only if certain characters are in the value. And browsers handle invalid attributes cleanly. Even data attributes are going to be considered invalid in old browsers, but should still work. It's a good suggestion though.